# Modulus of difference is bigger than modulus of difference of modulus

Tags: real-analysis

Simple question:

Can anyone provide a formal proof for:
$$|a-b| \geq ||a|-|b||.$$

Thanks.

Comment: How would you prove this using number-testing?

Comment: José Carlos Santos, sorry, I was mistaken. Given the formulation of my sentence the phrase inside the parenthesis was unnecessary.

Comment: The word modulus here is technically correct but would be better to call it absolute value given that this has been tagged as a real analysis question. Modulus implies you are working with complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. I'll make sure I make the distinction next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the reverse triangle inequality.
$$
|a|=|b+(a-b)|\leq|b|+|a-b|.
$$
So
$$\tag1
|a|-|b|\leq|a-b|.
$$
Now repeat with the roles reversed to get
$$\tag2
|b|-|a|\leq|b-a|=|a-b|.
$$
Now combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ to get 
$$
|\,|a|-|b|\,|\leq|a-b|.
$$

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since both sides are nonnegative, we can check that the inequality holds for the squares:
$$
|a-b|^2\ge\bigl||a|-|b|\bigr|^2
$$
becomes
$$
a^2-2ab+b^2\ge a^2-2|a|\,|b|+b^2
$$
that's equivalent to
$$
ab\le |ab|
$$
which is true.